# Excluding other Logging dependencies and use Log4j2 only in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, log4j

I have been recently working on a Spring Boot project where i had to use Log4j2 for logging. I realise that spring boot by default uses Logback. So, when i try to run the application, it gives me warning saying that multiple classes have been identified for logging (If what i understood is correct).

Is there a way to exclude all the available logging packages and prioritise Log4j2 ? If so, what changes should i make to the pom file? Below is the code for reference:

Warning Message:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/prabhandamsuhas/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/prabhandamsuhas/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.14.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from com.ecommerce.demo.repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ecommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Adding to that I realised that it wasnt using log4j as the pattern of message used in the console logging was different as compared to that i mentioned in my log4j2.xml file (Printing the date pattern). So is everything mentioned right in my file?
Console Message:

```
2021-06-15 18:14:23.376  INFO 86780 --- [  restartedMain] com.ecommerce.demo.DemoApplication       : This Info
2021-06-15 18:14:23.377  WARN 86780 --- [  restartedMain] com.ecommerce.demo.DemoApplication       : This Warn
2021-06-15 18:14:23.377 ERROR 86780 --- [  restartedMain] com.ecommerce.demo.DemoApplication       : There is some error
2021-06-15 18:14:23.377 ERROR 86780 --- [  restartedMain] com.ecommerce.demo.DemoApplication       : This Fatal
```

log4j.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{dd-MM-yyyy ' T ' HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">c:/temp</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="appLog"
                     fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/SpringBoot2App/application.log"
                     filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/SpringBoot2App/application-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.ecommerce.demo" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Note: After observing on some websites, i also tried to add exclude tag for "spring-boot-starter-logging" in "spring-boot-starter-web" dependency. This didnt make any difference.

Comment: any guide/ resources on how to properly use log4j2 would be really useful as im in learning stage of my career